# if rotation < -45 && > -140 issue

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, rotation

I have a problem with this if statement.

If the rotation is < -45. And > -140

Then this statement would be true when the rotation is = -90?

And it would be false if the rotation is = -170?

I'm using the negative values because unity rotation goes from -180 to +180.

I tried using a full 360 scale, that also didnt work.
that Statement looked like:

if the rotation is > 245 & < 325

Then do stuff

If you can change where the 0 value of the rotation is from the West point to a different one would also be a useful option

Thanks for any help

Code that is being executed:

```
        if (transform.rotation.z > -140 && transform.rotation.z < -45)
    {
        if(rotationSpeed < 150f)
        {
            rotationSpeed += 150f * Time.deltaTime;
        } else
        {
            rotationSpeed = 150f;
        }
        print("135");

    } else
    {
        if(rotationSpeed > 70f)
        {
            rotationSpeed -= 150f * Time.deltaTime;
        } else
        {
            rotationSpeed = 70f;
        }
        print("246");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [Transform.rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) is a Quaternion. This is why I can't use the `z` value from it.

The [Transform.localEulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) does use 0 to 360, so changing the parameters of the `if` statement will solve any issues:

```
if (transform.localEulerAngles.z > 250 && transform.localEulerAngles.z < 325)
{
    if(rotationSpeed < 150f)
    {
        rotationSpeed += 150f * Time.deltaTime;
    } else
    {
        rotationSpeed = 150f;
    }
    print("135");

} else
{
    if(rotationSpeed > 70f)
    {
        rotationSpeed -= 150f * Time.deltaTime;
    } else
    {
        rotationSpeed = 70f;
    }
    print("246");
}
```